# XNAT SimpleUploadPlugin - How to include jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, gradle, include, build.gradle, xnat

I am making changes to the XNAT SimpleUploadPlugin and wish to include validation using jQuery Validate. I can not find out where to include the cdns:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

I placed them in the SimpleUploadPlugin.vm above the bootstrap style sheet cdn:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However, this did not work. I have tried looking for where the jquery.min.js is included so I can place the CDNs there; however, I can not find that. I also checked build.gradle and could not see anything obvious in there.

Comment: Isn't this more of a generic question?  Like, where is jQuery included or how to do JavaScript file includes?  Because, if you know how/where these scripts are loaded, then you can include any plugin or file.

Comment: Hi Sparky, if you can answer any of these questions, then I would be very grateful. Kind regards, Glyn

Comment: I don’t.  But I’m making sure it’s titled and tagged correctly so the right people will see it.